# how can i bind the event by resizing

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

so i have the widget and it's size_hint_x is .5, i want to change it when  window.width will be bigger than window.height to .3, for some reason on_resize does not work the way  i wanted it  to
here is the code

```
def on_resize(self):
        if self.width>self.height:
            self.ids.left_panel.size_hint_x=.3
        else:
            self.ids.left_panel.size_hint_x=.5
```

Does on_resize function work different from what i thought?
Also, what is a good way to get your current window size?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the `Window` size, like this:

```
    Window.bind(size=self.on_resize)
```

Comment: where do i bind it? In the build function?